# English word for the Afrikaans word "bies"

Tags: terminology

I tried google translate with no luck. This may be a translation of a word only a person who has spent time on a farm would know. When a cow gives birth to a calf there is a type milk that the calf has to drink soon after birth. It has a yellow tint to it and contains the antibodies that are crucial to the calfs survival. This is also consider to be a truly remarkable type of milk. In Afrikaans this yellow milk is called bies. I was wondering what the English version of this word was?

Comment: Have you tried searching for `calf first milk` with a web search engine of your choice?

Answer (score 3):

Humans have this kind of milk too, it's called *colostrum*.

There is another word, "*beestings*" in the dictionary. I'd not heard this word, but it seems to be more agricultural than medical. It's clearly cognate with the Afrikaans word. It seems more common in Irish dialects.

Comment: Humans, and also every other mammal produce colostrum.

Comment: Well, I'm neither Irish nor from a farming background, but I immediately thought of _beestings_, a  word I knew from general reading.